# High Memory usage with no app. Can't work on Android Studio

Tags: windows, android-studio

My computer has 8GB of RAM, nVidia GT-710 2GB and is running on i5-7400 @ 3.00 GHz with latest Windows 10(no SSD). I've seen that with every update of Android Studio, it's getting hard to work. Even with after closing every app and stopping every unnecessary service, it shows 50% of memory usage. I even close nVidia software, other windows apps, update services. And, when I open Android Studio or with Google chrome, it goes to 95%+ memory usage. It gets very hard to work with Android Studio and Google chrome as Android Studio keeps showing out of memory error or goes in not responding mode every two minutes with hell like lagging. 
[image]

I need chrome with Android studio to access the docs and all so I'm kinda stuck right now. To optimize further, I've disabled every chrome extension too except tab suspender which suspends tab after 1 minute to reduce the memory usage. I've tried searching support from Microsoft but they suggested only one thing - `sfc /scannow` in most answers which doesn't help. My harddrive is also only partially full, also I've premium Avast Antivirus for virus protection.

As in these conditions, I'm unable to upgrade or improve the hardware.

So, is there any configuration, tweak or a tool which can improve the performance so I can work?

Edit: Android Studio's VM options if needed:

```
# custom Android Studio VM options, see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

These were something else so I changed them according to the recommendation on StackOVerflow.

Comment: check your pagefile size, it could be too small. Out of memory errors usually occur when windows runs out of virtual address space, e.g. ram+pagefile. Also, a screenshot of the performance tab of task manager would help to see what's going on.

Comment: @1NN [This](https://imgur.com/a/ckCB9k2) is the page file SS which shows 9744 MB allocated. And [this](https://imgur.com/a/gYP42hN) is the performance tab of Task Manager with no software, windows app or random services like Windows update as Android Studio died after not responding for 10 minutes.

Comment: I also have MSI RamDisk software installed which makes a seperate drive for paging.

Comment: if the problem arises only when chrome is open, too, i'd try to look at the memory usage of chrome. Maybe some extension is eating up the remaining ram: the 2GB ram you have free should be more than enough. Press shift&esc in chrome to bring up the chrome task manager. Check what is using your ram. maybe disable some plugins

Comment: You've got 8GB of RAM but your RamDisk is greater than 8GB. How does that work?

Comment: @1NN as you said 2gb ram is free, yes, it is free but that android studio was stuck, neither not responding nor working and I wasn't even using chrome either. So, on this if I use chrome too then both gets laggy and either doesn't work. And as I said earlier I've disabled every extensions and I also keep an eye on its task manager which shows nothing except main app, gpu process, network service, only one tab at a time and tab suspender, nothing else.

Comment: @DavidMarshall if you're talking about the RamDisk software then it's set on 2GB which I don't know why never seems to be used and if about page files, then you can see the configuration [here](https://imgur.com/a/ckCB9k2). I don't know if it works or not.

Comment: I think you probably need more RAM. I don't think the RamDisk is helping. You seem to have paging files spread amongst partitions on the same physical disk. With a HDD that's not ideal. If you can't make any hardware modifications, I would uninstall the RamDisk and just create one pagefile on the same partition as Windows. Try a size of 8GB.

Comment: @DavidMarshall Thanks for the help. Currently, I've set it to manage automatically and it has covered a huge chunk of my main drive. Apart from this, I've decided to get a 8gb ram and a 256GB SSD once the delivery service starts.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar 16GB of RAM (2x 8GB DIMMs) would be recommended as the minimum RAM to have.  While not related to your issue, an FYI regarding `SFC`: _Before_ running `SFC /ScanNow`, `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` should always be run first, then `SFC /ScanNow`, due to what each does.  Running `SFC` prior to `/RestoreHealth` is an absolute, literal waste of time.

Comment: @JVV0914 Thanks, I'll definitely upgrade the ram after this lockdown. Also, thanks for these commands, I'm going to run them to make things better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cite from the [MSI Ramdisk users guide](https://www.msi.com/files/pdf/RAMDISK_User_GuideEN.pdf) :

> RAMDISK creates a virtual RAM drive using the available memory in your computer, the performance of the RAMDISK is faster than an SSD and hard drive. RAMDISK allows you to store any temporary information on it.

Then I cite from [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/171432/ram-disks-explained-what-they-are-and-why-you-probably-shouldnt-use-one/):

> To create a RAM disk, you would install a third-party program that creates a virtual drive in Windows. This program would reserve a section of your RAM — so if you had 4 GB of files in your RAM disk, the disk would take up 4 GB of RAM. All the files on your disk would be stored in your RAM. When you wrote to the disk, you’d just be writing to a different section of your RAM.

This means that ramdisk has reserved part of your RAM, and it is not available for other applications. That's why you have 2GB RAM "free" - but in reality reserved by ramdisk. And your apps have no way to access these 2GB!!

Uninstall MSI Ramdisk and your pains will be over.

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy. Now, I got to know that why that RamDisk was always empty, it was made for my use as an SSD or even faster than it. For now, I've not uninstalled it, instead I've copied the android studio in it and it's working very very fast and that's all I need. Thanks you so much for the help.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar I'm glad it works for you. But consider that ramdisk can ONLY really speed up your system if you have more RAM available than what your system would normally use. See that second link in my answer for explanations.

Comment: Although, I deleted the RamDIsk and removed the software last night because after working fine for half an hour, Android studio started lagging. So today, it has begun its tantrums again, the only app open is Android Studio and it works fine for about half an hour then gets stuck, just a greyish window, no elements and not even not responding, then I've to close it from task manager and restart it again. I think it has some flaws because of which it works fine for sometime and then comes to the same conditions. Even the memory usage stays at 74% but it doesn't work.

Comment: I really don't know what to do, it's been a week and I haven't been able to write 20 lines of code because of it.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar I'm sorry to hear you're still having issues. I reccomend you start a new question with the problems about Android Studio, so you have more people which will respond than to a question with already a solution. Be sure to include qhat you have done so far. In the meantime maybe you can try to: a) run a registry cleaner. b) uninstall and reinstall Android Studio. c) move your pagefile to only one partition of your disk, instead of having it on several partitions. Good luck I'll kep my fingers crossed